# Python/wxPython: How to get text display in a second frame from the main frame

Tags: python, wxpython

Am new to Python/wxPython, I created a text two frames using `wxFormBuilder`. The purpose is to add two numbers and display the result on both frames `OnAdd` button click.

I have done all I could but no success?

My problem is how do I get the Final_Result display on the second frame that gets call when the add button is press as par the code below;

**Note:** the codes are in 3 separate files (q1.py,  q2.py, and q3.py). q2.py is the main running file while q1.py, and q2.py create the frames respectively as generated from wxFormBuilder.

**q1.py**

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString,   pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        Sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        Sizer2 = wx.GridSizer( 0, 2, 0, 0 )

        self.val1 = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.val1.SetFont( wx.Font( 30, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        Sizer2.Add( self.val1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.val2 = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.val2.SetFont( wx.Font( 30, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        Sizer2.Add( self.val2, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.Calc = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.Calc.SetFont( wx.Font( 30, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        Sizer2.Add( self.Calc, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.result = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Result", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        self.result.Wrap( -1 )
        self.result.SetFont( wx.Font( 30, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        Sizer2.Add( self.result, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        Sizer1.Add( Sizer2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( Sizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Calc.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.addFunc )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

#===================================================
```

**q2.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import wx
from q1 import MyFrame1
from q3 import MyFrame3


class MyFrame2(MyFrame1):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        MyFrame1.__init__ (self, parent)

    def addFunc( self, event ):
        val1 = float(self.val1.GetValue())
        val2 = float(self.val2.GetValue())

        add = val1 + val2

        self.result.SetLabel(str(add))

        self.result = MyFrame4(self)
        self.result.Show()

        self.Final_Result.SetLabel(str(add))



class MyFrame4(MyFrame3):
    """docstring for my_temp_Frame"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        MyFrame3.__init__ (self, parent)




if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App(0)
    MyFrame2(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()


#===================================================
```

**q3.py**

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

class MyFrame3 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,100 ), style = wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        Sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        Sizer2 = wx.GridSizer( 0, 2, 0, 0 )

        self.Text = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"You result is:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY )
        self.Text.SetFont( wx.Font( 20, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        Sizer2.Add( self.Text, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.Final_Result = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Final_Result", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        self.Final_Result.Wrap( -1 )
        self.Final_Result.SetFont( wx.Font( 30, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )
        self.Final_Result.SetForegroundColour( wx.Colour( 255, 255, 255 ) )
        self.Final_Result.SetBackgroundColour( wx.Colour( 255, 0, 0 ) )

        Sizer2.Add( self.Final_Result, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        Sizer1.Add( Sizer2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( Sizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


#===================================================
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rarely seen a more convoluted way to simply have two frames in wxPython and transferring data from one into the other. But maybe you have your good reasons. If not, have a look at [this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController). It opened the eyes at least for me how to cleanly separate logic and GUI.

**Answer**: You should have got on calling:

```
    self.result = MyFrame4(self)
    # ...
    self.Final_Result.SetLabel(str(add))
```

the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'MyFrame2' object has no attribute 'Final_Result'
```

which simply means that there is no `Final_Result` in `MyFrame2`. After some looking `Final_result` can be found in `MyFrame3` which is the base class for `MyFrame4`. We also learn that `MyFrame4` is set as object attribute `self.result` in `MyFrame2`

So simply change the offending line to:

```
    self.result.Final_Result.SetLabel(str(add))
```

and you are done.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this line in `q2.py`:

```
self.Final_Result.SetLabel(str(add))
```

to this:

```
self.result.Final_Result.SetLabel(str(add))
```

Comment: Photofinish :) Sorry for interfering.

Comment: Thanks all, hope this will help someone in future